# Using Facebook or Google login API with Classic ASP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-api-client

I'm running a Classic ASP website, that has its own user authentication and login mechanism. For example, In order to remember a logged-in user, ASP creates an encrypted cookie and a 20-minute session for each connected user. If the 20 minute session is elapsed, the server revives the session from the cookie saved previously, and saves some data regarding the user to the database.

I want to to be able to allow users to connect with their Facebook or Google identity, but the mechanism used by Facebook or Google is based mainly on Javascript and on client-side code.

1. How Facebook or Google login can be used while maintaining server side code in ASP? (So that the ASP server can still manage the session and save data regarding it, for example whenever a session is revived)
2. For me somehow it seems that it may become less secure to use client-side authentication as the code may be altered easily. Isn't this the case?
3. If I use client-side javascript and log in with Facebook, how would I update the user data retrieved from facebook back into my database, for example the user's first and last name?
4. For me it sounds that it should be a "server-to-server" communication (between my ASP server and Facebook's or Google's servers) and what they propose is a "client-to-server" communication ... Any ideas how this can be done?

Any help or explanation would be very much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with my question? Why did I get -1 for asking it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to address your Facebook-related questions one by one. However, I will not give you an implementation or any ASP-specific feedback, but only a rough approach. Additionally, I recommend that you study Facebook's [documentation on Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login) extensively to further your understanding of the matter.

**1.** Facebook documents the server-side OAuth 2.0 flow in their [Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow) guide. Basically you redirect the user to a specific FB URL that (in the parameters) tells FB to render the "Login with Facebook" dialog, and which permission scopes to ask for. Once the user approves the Facebook Login for your webapp, they will be redirected back to your web app, e.g. with an OAuth token in the query string, that your webserver can then exchange for a user access token.
Once you obtained a user access token, you could e.g. store it in your web app user's session.

**2.** I don't know what you mean. Client side apps are fairly secure. Perhaps you can convince yourself about how secure JS apps are when reading about things like [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

**3.** If you only use JavaScript (e.g. Facebook's [JS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript)) and you want to store e.g. app-scoped user IDs on your server, you need to expose an endpoint on your server that your JS application can submit that kind of information to.

**4.** You state

> what they propose is a "client-to-server" communication

Who are "they", and where are the proposing this? The resources I linked to in **1.** should explain how you can use Facebook login in a pure server-to-server way.